# preg_replace issiue with "æ" and "ø" smal letter

Tags: php

I have a smal issiue with replacing the letters æ and ø.

My function:

```
function getACoolString($string){
    return strtolower(preg_replace("/[^A-Åa-å0-9-]/", '', $string));
}


echo getACoolString('Æ');
```

This one gives the result: æ

but this one:

```
  echo getACoolString('æ');
```

Gives me nothing, seams like the big capital letters become smal, and the smal dont work at all.

Any working fix for this?

Comment: What is the purpose of your `preg_replace` there, exactly?

Comment: make it case insensitive: /[^A-Åa-å0-9-]/i

Comment: @Loupax Seems he want to remove stuff from the string, so preg_replace is ok.

Comment: Oh I misread this, sorry. Deleting the original comment

Comment: String cleans unwanted chars, to make a nice url. why im using it is not important, the soulution is.

Comment: Can not reproduce. But i have to use `mb_strtolower()` to get `'Æ' => 'æ'` and `'æ' becomes 'æ'`

Comment: Shouldn't æ replaced with '' in the preg_replace? Is æ outside of the range  `a-å`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to make your regex case insensitive and it will work, i.e.:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-å\d-]/i', '', $string);
```

---

[Regex Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/i3tT1S/2/)